# turn off windows explorer file-specific "extensions" in windows 8 (picture tools, video tools etc)

Tags: windows, windows-8

This is annoying, windows 8 systematically comes back with "picture" tools or other rubbish view in Windows Exploer. Is there some way to turn this off permanently and simply stay with default folder view I set?

Comment: I would love to know this as well - 6 months and no answer is worrisome. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm a musician and "Music Tools" stopped my workflow in its tracks.

http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/can-not-see-music-file-extensions.5010/

Right click the folder or parent container if the issue involves multiple subfolders.

Choose properties

Select the Customize tab

Change the drop down from Music to General items and check the box to "Also apply this template to all subfolders"

Answer (score 0):

The advice in [this article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsvista/ht/vistatnpreviews.htm) seems to work in Windows 8 as well - I just tried it and now my Downloads folder actually opens in less than 30 seconds :)

- Ribbon "View" tab
- "Options" button (on the right for me)
- "View" tab in the "Folder Options" dialog that comes up
- top option in "Advanced settings" is a checkbox for "Always show icons, never thumbnails"

It didn't quite work on the window I had open, but once I closed it and opened explorer again to the folder, it worked great (no 'Picture Tools', loaded fast).