# Turn off windows explorer file-specific "extensions" (picture tools, video tools etc) for ALL FOLDERS

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-explorer

How do I get rid of this incredibly annoying "Music Tools" setting?

[image: Windows Explorer in Music Tools mode]

For those of you not familiar with it, if you have a folder with some audio files in it (no idea what the exact criteria are), Windows decides that what you really want is to not see file size or type or modification date, but rather #, Title, Contributing artists, and Album.  That's fine for many situations, but for the multimedia processing I am doing, I need Windows Explorer to work like it always does.

The [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/629439/turn-off-windows-explorer-file-specific-extensions-in-windows-8-picture-tools) is basically the same, except that the previous answer tells you how to fix this individually for each folder that Windows has messed up.  I'm really hoping in the 7 years since this question was originally posted, somebody at Microsoft came to their senses and created a way to turn off this annoying feature once and for all.

I feel like in some previous incarnation of Windows, Clippy popped up and said "Hey!  It looks like you have a folder with music, do you want to set it to Music Tools?" and they got rid of Clippy but kept the feature ...

Comment: What's bothering you? The `Music Tools` Ribbon or the default Music `FolderType` columns? If you had the folders in a hierarchy and set the top level to `General Items` AND used the `Also apply this template...` checkbox, that should take care of the column issue.

Comment: Another tack to deal with columns would be to set the columns you want in a folder using the `Musci` `FolderType`, then use `View` -> `Options` -> `VIew` tab -> `Aooly to Folders` to make Music folders use the same columns as `Generic` folders.

Comment: Waiting for clarification before I go poking around in the registry...

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple fix, just not simple to find the answer. Your question was EXACTLY what mine was.
I have Windows 8. Go to Home>>> Properties >>> Customize>> chose optimize this folder for documents. Then apply. All the file details should be back.

I had the same issue and fixed it.